# Rails implementation of Two-level JQuery check and uncheck all child checkboxes of a parent checkbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Trying to implement a multiple (parent/child) checkbox set, where "check all" checks all boxes, and unchecking one of the child boxes unchecks "check all." Have found several solutions online but none using Ruby on Rails.  One solution that looked promising utilized simple HTML and a jQuery script. The basic HTML looked like this--the classes were referenced in the jQuery code in order to identify the checkboxes:

```
<html>
   <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1-1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1-2<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1-3<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1-4<br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1-5<br />
    </fieldset>
</html>
```

I generated a simple scaffold in Rails to test out ideas, using a parent and 3 children. Generic scaffold code looks like this:

```
<fieldset>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :checkall %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :checkall %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date_one %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_one %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date_two %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_two %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date_three %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_three %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %> 

</fieldset>
```

Rails API shows this as check_box syntax:

```
check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

...and gives an example:

```
check_box("eula", "accepted", { class: 'eula_check' }, "yes", "no")
 # => <input name="eula[accepted]" type="hidden" value="no" />
 #    <input type="checkbox" class="eula_check" id="eula_accepted" name="eula[accepted]" value="yes" />
```

...but I'm grasping at straws here because I'm not sure of definitions, syntax, etc.  Trying to take that simple HTML above and translate it into rubyspeak, I came up with this:

```
<fieldset>

  <div class="parentCheckbox">
    <%= f.label :checkall %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :checkall, {class: parentCheckBox} %>
  </div>
  <div class="childCheckBox">
    <%= f.label :date_one %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_one, {class: childCheckBox} %>
  </div>
  <div class="childCheckBox">
    <%= f.label :date_two %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_two, {class: childCheckBox} %>
  </div>
  <div class="childCheckBox">
    <%= f.label :date_three %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :date_three, {class: childCheckBox} %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %> 

</fieldset>
```

...and got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `parentCheckBox' for #<#<Class:0xbdcb5e4>:0xc07ab8c>
Extracted source (around line #18):
15 
16 <div class="parentCheckbox">
17 <%= f.label :checkall %><br>
18 <%= f.check_box :checkall, {class: parentCheckBox} %>
19 </div>
```

I'm sure I'm way off the mark here, but the API was of very little help in translating what should be very simple HTML into embedded ruby.  I know the jQuery script works with the HTML, but I need the results of the submitted form to feed the database, not just look pretty in the display, so I'm trying not to mess with the rails generated code too much.

Lost.

Answer (score 0):

<%= f.check_box :checkall, {class: 'parentCheckBox'} %> - add '' to string ('parentCheckBox')